# where to see the SQL query time?

Tags: mvc-mini-profiler

I'm new to using the mini profiler tool, so please forgive my beginner's question.  I notice my report shows 89.9ms for 37 sql queries:

```
duration (ms)       from start (ms)         query time (ms)

Executing action: show      12457.7 +258.0          37 sql  89.9
```

is 89.9ms the actual time to execute the queries, or is there somewhere else I need to get the actual number?